# Accessing Flixster data

Tags: api, sdk, rss, opensocial

Is there any way of accessing the data on Flixster?  Specifically, I'd like to retrieve a list of all of my movie ratings.  I know you can get an rss feed of these, but it only appears to return a subset of all of the ratings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a new-ish Rotten-Tomatoes API at http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/docs/read/json/v10/Movie_Reviews

Comment: Thank you, do you know if this API can retrieve a list of ratings for a particular user?

Comment: Sorry I haven't read your question fully. Currently from what I could see it's only possible to get critics reviews. But if you submit your needs on the feature request page they might do it! http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/forum/topics/100323

Answer (score 2):

View your Rotten Tomatoes / Flixster movie ratings by accessing this URL, first replacing USERIDHERE in the URL.
http://community.flixster.com/api/v1/users/USERIDHERE/ratings.rss

You can find out your user id by clicking to view your Profile, which will contain your unique id in the URL, such as:
http://www.flixster.com/user/USERIDHERE/

Comment: Do you know of a URL to get ALL of my ratings ? With the URL you provided I get only the latest 3

Comment: The API seems to have been updated, try  http://www.flixster.com/api/users/USERIDHERE/movies/ratings ...  

"Want to see" would be http://www.flixster.com/api/users/USERIDHERE/movies/ratings?scoreTypes=wts

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple program, using the API, that I've found:
https://github.com/mmihaljevic/flixter

...and you can read her [blog post](http://melitamihaljevic.blogspot.dk/2012/08/sunday-hacking-get-your-movie-ratings.html) for more information.

Just tested both fetching and parsing, and it still appears to work.